# instagram embedded browser not displaying flexbox correctly

Tags: html, flexbox, instagram

links within instagram are opened in some sort of custom browser

this simple flexbox layout works fine in all browser but in the embedded browser the footer is off screen. what browser is that? how to debug?

css

```
.container { height:100%; display: flex }
.conent { flex-grow: 1 }
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

update: I believe issue is caused by the height: 100vh (because if you scroll down the footer shows up)

is called in-app browser and for iOs it seems to be safari